# using strings as a pointer to its first character

Tags: c++, c, string

```
int main()  
{
    char name[]="avinash";   
    const char* nameano="a";   
    strtok(name,"n");   
    cout<<"the size of name is"<< sizeof(name);   
    cout<< name;
}
```

`strtok` takes in arguments `(char*, const char*)`; `name` is an array, and hence a pointer to its first element. But if we make a declaration like

```
string name="avinash";
```

and pass `name` as first argument to `strtok`, then the program doesn't work, but it should, because `name`, a string, is a pointer to its first character.

Also, if we write

```
const string n = "n";
```

and pass it as second argument it doesn't work; this was my first problem.

Now also the `sizeof(name)` output is 8, but it should be 4, as `avinash` has been tokenized. Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't believe `sizeof(name)` should change. Note that `sizeof` is not the same as `strlen`...

Comment: You should really learn how to format you code and text in a question (See the editing help on the "ask question" page, and use less "..." in you text). Also, it's not very clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I have cleaned up the question, hope I got everything right.

Comment: @matteo italia....thanks for editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing several things.

> strtok takes in arguments (char*, const char*)....name is an array and hence a pointer to its first element...

`name` is an array, and ***it's not*** a pointer to its first element. An array *decays* in a pointer to its first argument in several contexts, but in principle it's a completely different thing. You notice this e.g. when you apply the `sizeof` operator on a pointer and on an array: on an array you get the array size (i.e. the cumulative size of its elements), on a pointer you get the size of a pointer (which is fixed).

> but if we made a declaration like string name="avinash" and passed name as argument
>   then the prog doesnt work but it should because name of string is a pointer to its first character...

If you make a declaration like

```
string name="avinash";
```

you're are saying a completely different thing; `string` here is not a C-string (i.e. a `char[]`), but the C++ `std::string` type, which is a class that manages a dynamic string; those two things are completely different.

If you want to obtain a constant C-string (`const char *`) from a `std::string` you have to use it's `c_str()` method. Still, you can't use the pointer obtained in this way with `strtok`, since `c_str()` returns a pointer to a **`const`** C-string, i.e. it cannot be modified. Notice that `strtok` is not intended to work with C++ strings, since it's part of the legacy C library.

> also if we write const string n = "n"; and pass it as second argument it doesnt work...this was my first problem...

This doesn't work for the exact same motivation, but in this case you can simply use the `c_str()` method, since the second argument of `strtok` is a ***`const`*** `char *`.

> now also the sizeof(name) output is 8 but it should be 4 as avinash has been tokenised..

`sizeof` returns the "static" size of its operand (i.e. how much memory is allocated for it), it knows nothing about the content of `name`. To get the length of a C-string you have to use the `strlen` function; for C++ `std::string` just use its `size()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass your name[] array to strtok like this:

```
strtok(&name[0],"n");
```

Comment: If `name` is a C-string, the syntax used by the OP (`strtok(name, "n")`) is already ok. If, instead, `name` is an `std::string`, you are potentially violating the preconditions of `strtok`, since nothing guarantees you that it's internal buffer is NULL-terminated (and actually it could even contain a NULL before the end of the string, since `std::string`s can contain any character).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `strtok` is C and not C++ and is not made to work with C++ strings. Plus, it cant work if you dont use the return result of the function.

```
char name[]="avinash";   
char * tok_name = strtok(name,"n");   
std::cout<<"the size of name is"<< sizeof(tok_name);   
std::cout<< tok_name;
```

You should consider to use `std::string::find`, `std::string::substr` and other stuff from the STL library instead of C functions.

Comment: `strtok` can be used in c++ as well.

Comment: Right, but it is a bad idea imho.

Comment: `strtok` is C++, for the same reason that most of the C library is C++.  Still, `strtok` was already broken in C, and shouldn't have been used there, much less in C++.  And C++ has a lot of more powerful tools to achieve the same ends: both the member functions of `std::string` and the algorithms in the standard library.

Comment: C functions are usable in C++. For me, it does not mean that they are C++. I think a lot of people will agree that C++ is not exactly an extension of C. This is an old debate ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the actual size of the name array is ever changed when you call strtok.  The call remembers the last location it was called if you pass it a null pointer, and it continues to tokenize the string.  The return value of the strtok call is the token that has been found in the string provided.  Your code is calling sizeof(name) which is never actually adjusted by the strtok function.

```
int main()
{
   char name[] = "avinash";
   const char* nameano = "a";
   char* token;
   token = strtok(name, "n"); 
   cout << "the length of the TOKEN is" << strlen(token) << endl;
   cout << token << endl;
   cout << "the length of the string is" << strlen(name) << endl;
   cout << name << endl;
}
```

Try this maybe?  I am not in front of a compiler so its likely I made a mistake, but it should get you on the right track to solve this problem.

This might also help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `strtok` takes arguments of type `char *` and `const char *`.  A `string` is not a `char *` so passing it as the first argument will not compile.  For the second argument, you can convert a string to a `const char *` using the `c_str()` member function.

What problem are you trying to solve?  If you're just trying to learn how `strtok` works, it would be much better to stick to raw character arrays.  That function is inherited from C and thus wasn't designed with C++ strings in mind.